# Backbone fetch models based on filter

Tags: backbone.js

```
initialize: function(){
    this.collection = app.RequestLines;
    this.subView = app.TransportationLineView;

    this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.addOne );
    this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.addAll );

    this.collection.fetch();

    this.render();
}
```

On this context, the view would fetch all the models on the database. How can I only fetch the models filter on a property. I have defined a filter on my collection to do this:

```
   byTransportation: function(){
        return this.where( {transportationConfirmation: true} );
    }
```

This is when the event **add** is triggered then when a model is appended to the view.

Comment: You want the collection to fetch only filtered results from server, or filter the collection at client side after fetching all the data from server..? If it's the first case, obviously you'll have to implement the logic at server side.

Comment: It would be the second case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `parse` method of collection to filter the data from backend and update the collection with the filtered result:

```js
var SomeCollection = Backbone.collection.extend({
  // Other stuff
  filterResponse: false,
  filterStuff: function(stuff) {
    if(!stuff)
     stuff = this.models;
    return _.where(stuff, { // need to use _ since stuff will not always
                            // be a collection instance(when invoked from parse)
      something: true
    });
  },
  parse: function(response) { // invoked after obtaining response from server
                              // and before updating it to collection
    if(this.filterResponse)
      return this.filterStuff(response);
    return response;
  }
});
```

Comment: I want to filter whenever I call "that", not everytime I fetch something from the server. Sometimes I do want to fetch all models.

Comment: How would I refer to the items in the collection instead of saying 'stuff'.?

Comment: @DiegoGallegos you refer to the models using `this.models`, stuff is whatever you pass to filterStuff. ou can see that I assign `this.models` to stuff if something is not manually passed to filter function. if you want to conditionally filter fetched items, you can set a flag on the collection and avoid filtering based on the flag in `parse`. it's simple logic isn't it? see the update